# Dynamic where condition in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following:

```
IQueryable<Post> posts = _context.Posts;
String rank = "1";
posts = posts.Where(x => x.Rank == rank);
```

I would like to create a Where extension in order to use it like this:

```
posts = posts.Where(x => x.Rank, rank);
```

Which would translate into `posts.Where(x => x.Rank == rank)`.

I am passing the property to be applied (x.Rank) and the rule (rank)

The reason why I am using this is because rank rule could be:

```
[minRank;maxRank], [;maxRank], [minRank;], etc.
```

So I will build the query based on a set of rules. For example:

```
// [minRank;maxRank]:
posts = posts.Where(x => x.Rank >= minRank && x.Rank <= maxRank);

// [;maxRank]:
posts = posts.Where(x => x.Rank <= maxRank);
```

There will be more rules that I will plan to add.

The steps I am considering to build the query would be:
1. Parse the rule info;
2. Check which rule type is (equals, range, ...)
3. Check the type of x.Rank
4. Create the Where query for that rule with that property.

Comment: How would you differentiate between posts.Where(x => x.Rank, minRank); and posts.Where(x => x.Rank, maxRank);

Comment: Give us a little bit more scenarios so we can think of a good abstraction.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the predicate or condition in the `Where` ?

Comment: @bit: Not sure what your "dynamically" means but I know to which property I need to apply the condition (for example, Rank). It is just the condition type and values that is undefined since is passed to the API

Comment: In that case a simple `if else` or a `switch` should suffice and you will still have to write the respective `Where` conditions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
public static class Extentions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T, P>(this IQueryable<T> self, Func<T, P> selector, P value) 
        where P : IComparable
    {
        return self.Where(x => selector(x).CompareTo(value) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but at this case `P` should implement `IComparable` interface.